# CSS Float two block divs next to one image

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been toying around with CSS, and after much work, I was able to get the title and date to float to the right of my image. Now, I'm trying to make my `<div class='link'>` appear underneath my title/due date, but still float next to the circle image. Ideally, the final product will look something like this: REFERENCE PHOTO [image]

I've tried many different options such as `float` and `inline-block` on various elements but I've not found anything that works. I've considered doing another grid inside the grid area, but I want to stay away from too many grids if possible. Here's what I have so far.. if you have any solutions, I would be grateful to hear them! Any explanation as to how the solution works is also helpful so I can grow as a developer. Thank you!!!

```js
  function askHelp(arg) {

    var window = document.getElementsByClassName('moreInfo-window')[0];
    var questionbox = document.getElementById("questionbox");

    var helpBtn = document.getElementById('askforhelp');
    var doneBtn = document.getElementById('markdone');
    var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendmsg');
    var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelmsg');

    if (arg == "showform") {
      window.style.height = 'calc(auto + 100px)';
      questionbox.style.display = 'block';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'none';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'none';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'block';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (arg == "hideform") {
      window.style.height = 'auto';
      questionbox.style.display = 'none';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'block';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'block';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'none';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

```css
.modal {display: block !Important}

.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

  .moreInfo-window{
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 600px; height: auto;
   top: 50%; left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border-radius: 16px;
   background-color: white;
   transition: height 0.5s;}

  #moreInfo {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 56px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "top"
      "content"
      "controls";}

 /* --------[TOP] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-top {
   display: grid;
   grid-area: top;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #5B7042;
   grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 120px;}

 #moreInfo .big.pic{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 65px;
   clip-path: circle();
   margin-left: 10px;}

 #moreInfo .modal-top .title {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 26px}

 #moreInfo .due {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: gray;}

 .link{
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;}

 /* --------[CONTENT] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-content {
   display: block;
   grid-area: content;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   padding: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 30px}

 #moreInfo .directions {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.7}

 #moreInfo #questionbox {
   display: none;
   width: 100%; height: 100px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 18px !important;
   margin-top: 20px;}

 /* --------[CONTROLS] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-controls {
   grid-area: controls;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;}
   #moreInfo .modal-controls button {width: 49%}
   #moreInfo .modal-controls span {
     padding-top: 30px;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-style: italic;
     color: grey;}

 #askforhelp {margin-right: 10px;}

 #sendmsg {display: none; margin-right: 10px}
 #cancelmsg {display: none}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">

  <div id="infoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="moreInfo-window">
      <form id="moreInfo" action='task.int.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='assID' value='36'>
        <div class='modal-top'>
          <img class='big pic' src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
          <span class='title'>Something made today</span>
          <span class='due'>Due 2d ago</span>
          <div class='link'> https://drive.google.com/file/d/11d_EpOHIn0-PD1bieWaqDUKM75EoT/view?usp=drive_web&authuser=0</div>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='directions'>
            <b>Directions: </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor magna eget est lorem. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum.
          </div>
          <textarea id='questionbox' name='msg' placeholder='Type Question..'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-controls'>
          <button id='askforhelp' class='button green-btn' type='button' onclick='askHelp("showform")'>Ask for Help</button>
          <button id='markdone' class='button green-btn' name='markDone' type='submit'>Mark as Done</button>
          <button id='sendmsg' class='button green-btn' name='sendMsg'>Send Message</button>
          <button id='cancelmsg' class='button grey-btn' type='button' onclick='askHelp("hideform")'>Cancel Message</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below would work if you're not worried about the page being responsive to smaller screen sizes.

I'd strongly recommend looking into a CSS framework like Tailwind, Bulma, or Bootrap.

```js
function askHelp(arg) {

    var window = document.getElementsByClassName('moreInfo-window')[0];
    var questionbox = document.getElementById("questionbox");

    var helpBtn = document.getElementById('askforhelp');
    var doneBtn = document.getElementById('markdone');
    var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendmsg');
    var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelmsg');

    if (arg == "showform") {
      window.style.height = 'calc(auto + 100px)';
      questionbox.style.display = 'block';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'none';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'none';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'block';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (arg == "hideform") {
      window.style.height = 'auto';
      questionbox.style.display = 'none';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'block';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'block';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'none';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

```css
.modal {display: block !Important}

.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

  .moreInfo-window{
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 600px; height: auto;
   top: 50%; left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border-radius: 16px;
   background-color: white;
   transition: height 0.5s;}

  #moreInfo {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 56px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "top"
      "content"
      "controls";}

 /* --------[TOP] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-top {
   display: grid;
   grid-area: top;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #5B7042;
   grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;}

 #moreInfo .big.pic{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 65px;
   clip-path: circle();
   margin-left: 10px;}

 #moreInfo .modal-top .title {
   display: inline;
   align-items: center;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 26px}

 #moreInfo .due {
   float: right;
   display: inline;
   margin-top: 13px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: gray;}

 .link{
    float: right
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;}

 /* --------[CONTENT] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-content {
   display: block;
   grid-area: content;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   padding: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 30px}

 #moreInfo .directions {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.7}

 #moreInfo #questionbox {
   display: none;
   width: 100%; height: 100px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 18px !important;
   margin-top: 20px;}

 /* --------[CONTROLS] -------- */
 #moreInfo .modal-controls {
   grid-area: controls;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;}
   #moreInfo .modal-controls button {width: 49%}
   #moreInfo .modal-controls span {
     padding-top: 30px;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-style: italic;
     color: grey;}

 #askforhelp {margin-right: 10px;}

 #sendmsg {display: none; margin-right: 10px}
 #cancelmsg {display: none}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">

  <div id="infoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="moreInfo-window">
      <form id="moreInfo" action='task.int.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='assID' value='36'>
        <div class='modal-top'>
          <img class='big pic' src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
          <div>
            <div>
              <span class='title'>Something made today</span>
              <span class='due'>Due 2d ago</span>
            </div>
            <div class='link'> https://drive.google.com/file/d/11d_EpOHIn0-PD1bieWaqDUKM75EoT/view?usp=drive_web&authuser=0</div>
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='directions'>
            <b>Directions: </b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor magna eget est lorem. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum.
          </div>
          <textarea id='questionbox' name='msg' placeholder='Type Question..'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-controls'>
          <button id='askforhelp' class='button green-btn' type='button' onclick='askHelp("showform")'>Ask for Help</button>
          <button id='markdone' class='button green-btn' name='markDone' type='submit'>Mark as Done</button>
          <button id='sendmsg' class='button green-btn' name='sendMsg'>Send Message</button>
          <button id='cancelmsg' class='button grey-btn' type='button' onclick='askHelp("hideform")'>Cancel Message</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```